# Double quotes in String varibale in .NET not coming

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, double

I am trying to execute a cmd command from .NET and using the find cmd command as a pipe. But the find cmd command takes the value in string but when i am creating my string variable instead of taking double quotes it is replacing it with /"".

My string variable is "/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find \"START\"" and instead of passing "/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find "START"" this to cmd shell it is passing "/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find \"START\"" and my find command is failing.

Below is my .NET code

```
        string cmdstr = "/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find \"START\"";
        Process prc = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = cmdstr;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        prc.StartInfo = startInfo;

        prc.Start();

        string result;
        result = prc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        prc.WaitForExit(10);
```

When i debug the code the cmdstr value does not contain double quotes but it contains the \"

Comment: Yes.. in debug, whilst hovering, it will show them. At runtime, once evaluated.. they won't be escaped.

Comment: Have you tried @"/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find ""START""";? from here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594600/how-to-easily-display-double-quotes-in-strings-in-c

Comment: @Damon: That would only work in a verbatim string which the OP doesn't have. The escaping of his string is perfectly fine, the problem must be something else.

Comment: @Simon: Even i thought the same and it is such a simple thing but actually it not escaping the / and not taking the double quotes. Why i am saying this because my command works fine from cmd prompt but from .NET the find command text string is having \START\ which find is not able to find.

Comment: @Damon: I tried this also but during debugging the \ comes in the variable and the same gets passed to the cmd shell

Comment: I'm going to take a stab in the dark at this but didn't you intent to query "State" rather than "Start"? i.e  string cmdstr = "/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find \"STATE\""; Just a guess though... I've tried sc QUERY Alerter | find "STATE" and I got something a return value.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your code:
It's fine and equivalent to manually open up cmd.exe and type *sc QUERY ServiceName | find "START"*
If i change *ServiceName* to *W32Time* and *START* to *RUNNING*, then I even get a non empty result (on my machine).

Regarding the debugger:
The debugger shows you the not evaluated version of the string (i.e. that what you actually type in the code).
If you want to see the string with evaluated escape-sequences, than you must use the "Text-Quickview"-Dialog (I don't know the exact title in English):
[image: Open-Text-Quickview-Dialog-Button]
[image: Text-Quickview-Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

```
 string cmdstr = string.Empty;
 cmdstr = "/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find \"START\"";
 cmdstr = cmdstr.Replace("\"", "");

cmdstr ="/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find START";
```

-Hope it works .

Comment: What is that supposed to do? It replaces the double quotes with nothing, effectively removing them.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Have you tried it or just commented without testing it ??Is this code removing quotes???Please run it before concluding something ,and read question again the output which i provided is the desired output by questioner here .

Comment: Not correct. The line `cmdstr = cmdstr.Replace("\"", "");` removes all double quotes from `cmdstr`. Furthermore, the OP wants to pass `/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find "START"` as the parameter to `cmd.exe`. He doesn't want to pass `/c sc QUERY ServiceName | find START`.